# R dplyr mutate with HTML (or XML) documents, nodes, or node sets

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

I have a file with multiple HTML links in it and now want to use dplyr and rvest to get the link to the image per every link of each row.

When I do it manually it works fine and returns the row but when the same code is called within a function it fails with the following error:

> Error: no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of
>   class "factor"

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. In order to make my question more clear I have added (in comments) a few example rows and also shown the manual approach.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(httr) # contains function stop_for_status()

#get html links from file
#EXAMPLE

# "_id",url

# 560fc55c65818bee0b77ec33,http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/01/sriracha-ceviche-recipe.html
# 560fc57e65818bee0b78d8b7,http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2008/07/pasta-arugula-tomatoes-recipe.html
# 560fc57e65818bee0b78dcde,http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2007/08/cook-the-book-minty-boozy-chic.html
# 560fc57e65818bee0b78de93,http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/02/chipped-beef-gravy-on-toast-stew-on-a-shingle-recipe.html
# 560fc57e65818bee0b78dfe6,http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/05/dinner-tonight-quinoa-salad-with-lemon-cream.html
# 560fc58165818bee0b78e65e,http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/10/dinner-tonight-spicy-quinoa-salad-recipe.html

#
#load into SE
#
SE <- read.csv("~/Desktop/SeriousEats.csv")

#
#function to retrieve imgPath per URL
#using rvest
#      
getImgPath <- function(x) {

  imgPath <- x %>% html_nodes(".photo") %>% html_attr("src")
  stop_for_status(res)
  return(imgPath)
}

#This works fine
#UrlPage <- read_html ("http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/01/sriracha-ceviche-recipe.html")
#imgPath <- UrlPage %>% html_nodes(".photo") %>% html_attr("src")

#
#This throws an error msg
#
S <- mutate(SE, imgPath = getImgPath(SE$url))
```

Comment: try `mutate(SE, imgPath = getImgPath(url))`. I think by using `$` you're referencing the whole column when `mutate` is expecting to act row-by-row

Comment: also, please `dput` your `SE` object (or at least part of it).

Comment: Are the urls being read as factors? Try `stringsAsFactors=F` in your `read.csv` command?

Comment: nope. Error: no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: what is `res` in your `getImgPath()` function? I don't see it assigned anywhere in your code

Comment: it's supposed to show status, when going through rows. I took it out but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# SE <- data_frame(url = c(
#    "http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/01/sriracha-ceviche-recipe.html",
#    "http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2008/07/pasta-arugula-tomatoes-recipe.html"
# ))

SE <- read.csv('/path/to/SeriousEats.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

getImgPath <- function(x) {
    # x must be "a document, a node set or a single node" per rvest documentation; cannot be a factor or character
    imgPath <- read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".photo") %>% html_attr("src")
    # httr::stop_for_status(res) OP said this is not necessary, so I removed
    return(imgPath)
}

S <- SE %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(imgPath = getImgPath(url))
```

Comment: Thanks :) for catching that.

Comment: @DirkLX I updated with `rowwise()` to make it work per row of your file

Comment: @Jubbles sorry but I'm still confused. your first line makes no sense to me as I need to get the data from my file. I have changed it to this SE <- data.frame(read.csv("~/Desktop/SeriousEats.txt", stringsAsFactors = F)) but the outcome is not an additional row (mutate) with the image path.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and patience and @Jubbles. For the benefit of others here is the complete answer.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

SE <- read.csv("~/Desktop/FILE.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

getImgPath <- function(x) {

  if (try(url.exists(x))) {
  imgPath <- html(x) %>% 
            html_nodes(".photo") %>% 
              html_attr("src")
} 
else {
imgPath = "NA"
}
 #imgPath
 return(imgPath)
}

SE1 <- SE %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(imgPath = getImgPath(url))
```